# Spring Boot informix Jpa connection

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, informix

I am trying to create a web service application using informix RDBMS and Spring boot.

When I declare `ddl-auto = create` it works perfectly but when I change it to `update` or `none` I get the error. My informix version is Version 9.40.UC8.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:informix-sqli://*.*.*.*:*/testechange:INFORMIXSERVER=server
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=

spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE 

server.port=8182
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name ="todos")
public class Todo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer  id  ; 

    @Column
    private  String name   ;
}
```

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.informix/jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.6.20151104</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error accessing tables metadata

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error accessing tables metadata

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error accessing tables metadata
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Routine (get_data_type) can not be resolved.*
```

Comment: Before starting with `update` or `none` can you check if the table `todos` really exists in the db ?

Comment: i fixed  this  error  , just  i  change informix   JDBC version  to 4.50.2.fix

Answer (score 0):

When you use update you are indicating that the connection you will get with spring will be dynamic to which you can receive changes as you make them.